Error while building Docker image - load meta data error
I have a problem while working with amd64/nginx Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/amd64/nginx/):
FROM amd64/nginx:stable
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ./nginx/proxy.conf /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf
COPY ./data/ /var/www/html

When I try to build my image this error occurs:
#!/bin/bash
VERSION="v20240520"
docker build --no-cache --rm --force-rm -t proxy:${VERSION} .

and result:
[+] Building 1.0s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 188B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/amd64/nginx:stable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.9s
 => [auth] amd64/nginx:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/amd64/nginx:stable:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM amd64/nginx:stable
   2 |     COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
   3 |     COPY ./nginx/proxy.conf /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: amd64/nginx:stable: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/amd64/nginx:stable: no match for platform in manifest: not found

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/hwhe57r8ochec5yrotgzavlws

Image and version should exist but I am not able to download it from Docker Hub. I already tried advice to logout/login to Docker Hub account, delete ~/.docker/config.json etc. but no advice helped me.

Q: What is wrong with my Dockerfile?

no match for platform So on what platform are you? Why not just use nginx?
